# Is there any way to display a native windows or desktop notification with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications

I have tried to get a notification working on Chrome and Brave, but nothing is showed when I click the button. It does ask for permission the first time and if I refresh with a console.log, it shows 'granted. Therefore, it should be possible to create a new notification with the `new Notification();` constructor. The problem is that it just doesn't show anything.

I have checked the settings of the webpage and everything should be fine. I have a feeling that the support of Chrome does not work for the Notifications API anymore. Is there any better way to get notifications with Javascript, so if a certain data requirement is met, it shows a notification to all users/visitors?

And additionally, how to get the notification to show even if you have closed the page?

**CODE**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Notification Test</h1>
    <button onclick="notifyMe()">I want a notification!</button>
</div>

<script>
function notifyMe(){
    // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }

    // Let's check if the user is okay to get some notification
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        // If it's okay let's create a notification
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
        notification.show();
    }

    // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
    // Note, Chrome does not implement the permission static property
    // So we have to check for NOT 'denied' instead of 'default'
    else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

            // Whatever the user answers, we make sure we store the information
            if(!('permission' in Notification)) {
                Notification.permission = permission;
            }

            // If the user is okay, let's create a notification
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi please find an interesting walkthrough here:https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web

Comment: This is indeed an interesting walkthrough, but I feel I don't need the serviceworker or the push options. I just need a notification to show when for example: a>10. So if you have the website opened and a value of a is > 10, it should pop up a windows message. Is that possible with a bit easier setup?